# How can I write my schema so elements in sequence are mapped to separate properties instead of one List<Object> in JAXB-generated class?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I have the following types in my .xsd file:

```
<complexType name='FooType' mixed='true'>
  <sequence>
    <element name='Bar' minOccurs='0' type='xenc:BarType'/>
    <element name='Baz' minOccurs='0' type='base64Binary'/>
    <any namespace='##other' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
  </sequence>
  <attribute name='Moo' type='anyURI' use='required'/>
</complexType>

<simpleType name='BarType'>
  <restriction base="integer"/>
</simpleType>
```

...From which JAXB XJC generates the following in the `FooType` class:

```
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "Bar", namespace = "http://namespace.blargh", type = JAXBElement.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "Baz", namespace = "http://namespace.blargh", type = JAXBElement.class)
})
@XmlMixed
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
protected List<Object> content;
@XmlAttribute(name = "Moo", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
protected String moo;
```

I need access to the value of the `Bar` element, but it's in a `List<Object>` as a `JAXBElement`, and I'd have to hard-code the QName up in my business logic to make sure I have the right thing.

How can I modify my schema to get a `bar` property in the generated class? Either a `List<Integer>` or `List<BarType>` with a new class generated would work. (It's not ideal, but even `List<JAXBElement> bar` would work if I can know every item is a "Bar" element and only have to deal with the value.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing is: do you really need `mixed="true"`? This means that between all the child elements of a FooType you may also have content. This means that you need something to store a mixture of String (for the content before, between and after child elements), one Bar, one Baz and whatever comes for `xs:any`. Truly a wild mixture.

Without mixed, xjc generates:

```
public class FooType {
    @XmlElement(name = "Bar")
    protected BigInteger bar;
    @XmlElement(name = "Baz")
    protected byte[] baz;
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Moo", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected String moo;
```

(Do you really need BigInteger??)

If `mixed="true"` is required, you'll have to test the QName values. You might have had a small chance to avoid this if the classes of the List elements would be distinct, but String will occur vor the text children, the Baz element and later on ("any") everything is possible.

Not sure what has motivated exactly this XML Schema design, but better alternatives aren't inconceivable.

Comment: I didn't write the schema in the first place, so I'm not sure what motivated this design either, but your description of what "mixed" does explains a *lot*, and I can definitely remove it. I don't need BigInteger, no - I had just assumed "integer" was the type I wanted.

Comment: @Michelle `xs:integer` is arbitrary length, i.e. `BigInteger`, `xs:int` maps to Java `Integer` for an optional element (to allow `null` when the element is missing) and `int` for a required one.